# Panda tries to convert my strings into floats when I don't want it to

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

guys. I am writing a piece of code, which generates aminoacid sequences. It has two identical loops - the first one works fine, while the other one gives me the "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' ". Now, I tried debuggin it, setting everything as string, but it still doesn't work. The code is as follows:

```
from rdkit import Chem
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
import itertools

G='NCC(=O)O'
A='NC(C)C(=O)O'
V='NC(C(C)C)C(=O)O'
I='NC(C(C)CC)C(=O)O'
S='NC(CO)C(=O)O'
T='NC(C(O)C)C(=O)O'
C='NC(CS)C(=O)O'
U='NC(C[SeH])C(=O)O'
M='NC(CCSC)C(=O)O'
P='N1C(CCC1)C(=O)O'
K='NC(CCCCN)C(=O)O'
D='NC(CC(=O)O)C(=O)O'
E='NC(CCC(=O)O)C(=O)O'
N='NC(CC(=O)N)C(=O)O'
Q='NC(CCC(=O)O)C(=O)O'
H='NC(Cc1nc[nH]c1)C(=O)O'
F='NC(Cc1ccccc1)C(=O)O'
Y='NC(Cc1ccc(O)cc1)C(=O)O'
R='NC(CCCNC(=N)N)C(=O)O'
W='NC(Cc1c[nH]c2ccccc12)C(=O)O'

peptides=pd.DataFrame({'FASTA': [],'SMILES': []})
peptides['SMILES'].astype(str)

aminoAcidsFASTA=['G','A','V','I','S','T','C','U','M','P','K','D','E','N','Q','H','F','Y','R','W']
aminoAcidsSMILES=[G,A,V,I,S,T,C,U,M,P,K,D,E,N,Q,H,F,Y,R,W]
j=0
g=0
for i in range(0, 3):
    for fasta in itertools.permutations(aminoAcidsFASTA, i):
        fasta=''.join(fasta)
        peptides.at[j, 'FASTA']=fasta
        j=j+1
    for smiles in itertools.permutations(aminoAcidsSMILES, i):
        smiles=''.join(smiles)
        peptides.at[g, 'SMILES']=smiles
        g=g+1
peptides
```

Comment: Where in your code does the exact error message occur? It looks like the amino acids in the aminoAcidsSMILES are not encapsulated in quotes and may be causing the problem.

Comment: peptides.at[g, 'SMILES']=smiles <- it says that it can't convert '' into fload

Comment: I tried reverting the order of the loops so it generates smiles first and then fasta and this time the error appears on fasta (always the second loop). It looks like I am always able to do any one column but not both at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first add a value to the `"FASTA"` column, pandas populates the `"SMILES"` column  with a `nan`, which is a float. From there on, pandas thinks that column should only contain floats, and that causes your error.

Since you're dealing with strings, you can just add the following keyword argument when creating your DataFrame. Now your code should run fine:

```
peptides=pd.DataFrame({'FASTA': [],'SMILES': []}, dtype='object')
```

Let us know if you have any further issues!

Comment: It worked, although I had to write it like that: 'peptides=pd.DataFrame({'FASTA': [],'SMILES': [],}).astype(object)' Thank you.